# Ordenar pelo menor preço em uma tabela Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, classificação

Como listar os produtos que tenha o menor preço para o maior!

Do menor para o maior! Utilizando PHP e Mysql.

Comment: `ORDER BY ASC` no mysql.

Comment: Você já tem alguma coisa pronta e só precisa mesmo da sintaxe de sua *query* (que é justamente a resposta do *Earendul* - faltando apenas informar o nome do campo) ou você quer desde a conexão com o banco até a listagem dos dados em ordem crescente?

Answer (score 2):

Basta você adicionar este código no final do seu `select`:

```
ORDER BY `preco` Asc
```

Neste caso, você utiliza  `ASC` para ordenar de forma ascendente e `DESC` para ordenar de forma descendente.

Um `select` completo ficaria assim:

```
SELECT * FROM `produtos` ORDER BY `preco` Asc
```

Pode ver um exemplo utilizando `php` [neste link.](http://blog.thiagobelem.net/relacionamento-de-tabelas-no-mysql/)

Segue um exemplo no SqlFiddle: [Exemplo aqui](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9e4fd/4)

Comment: Já utilizei (ORDER BY valor DESC) para alguns produtos que eu busco ele funciona, mas para outros não, por exemplo:
Busquei um fone de ouvido, e retornou 2 fones de ouvidos, o primeiro da lista tem o valor de R$ 119,00 mas o segundo é de R$ 99,00

Ou seja, não está ordenando do menor para o maior!

No campo input para o usuário colocar o valor do produto, eu estou utilizando validação (maskMoney). E no campo da tabela eu defini como (VARCHAR 255)

Comment: Se possível, poste a estrutura de sua tabela, para que possa ajudar melhor. Utilize o fiddle com um exemplo, que assim posto a solução baseado em seu problema real.